# Set size and crop thumbnail in custom WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Setting the size for a thumbnail is not a problem, but I also want to crop the image from top and to the left, but it's not working!

Inside functions.php I have this code:

```
function theme_setup() {
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'primary' => __('Main Menu'),
        'footer' => __('Footer Menu'),
    ));

    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('thumbnail', 300, 300, true);
    add_image_size('post', 800,400,  true);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup');
```

I have tested to add this code inside the function:

```
 add_image_size('thumbnail', 300, 300, array( 'top', 'left'));
```

But it's not cropping from `top` `left`. All thumbnails are cropped `center` `center`

I saw this code on the WordPress Codex page:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 300, array( 'top', 'left')  );
```

If I should use this insted, how should I add this in functions.php to get it to work? I just tested to paste it in the code, but it's not working that either!

Any ideas why my code isn't working or suggestion how to improve the code?

EDIT: I forgot to write that I also has used the plugin Regenerate Thumbnails before I have changed the settings for the thumbnails.

Comment: It will be helpful 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: try this `add_image_size('thumbnail', 300, 300, array( 'left', 'top'));`

Comment: try this `add_image_size( 'custom-size', 300, 300, array( 'left', 'top' ) ); // Hard crop left top`